# React navigaton route.params undefined

Tags: javascript, react-native, graphql, react-navigation

I'm working on chat app using react naviagtion. There are 2 screens: room list - lists all available chat rooms with buttons to go to given room and room - basically chat window.

When trying to pass parameter to route via button I'm getting error "Cannot read property 'roomID' of undefined". I have done everything as per docs: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params

I want to pass this param (room.id I have from query) to make specific query when entering the given room.

Anyone has idea why it's not working?

This is my setup:

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen name="Home Screen / Room list" component={HomeScreen} />
          <Stack.Screen
            name="Room"
            component={RoomScreen}
            options={{ title: "Room id:" }}
          />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </ApolloProvider>
  );
}
```

```
function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(GET_ROOMS);
  if (loading) return <Text>Loading...</Text>;
  if (error) return <Text>Error :(</Text>;
  });

  return data.usersRooms.rooms.map((room: Room) => (
    <View
      style={{ width: 500, marginLeft: "auto", marginRight: "auto" }}
      key={room.id}
    >
      <View style={styles.roomListItem}>
        <Image
          style={styles.roomPic}
          source={{
            uri:
              room.roomPic !== ""
                ? room.roomPic
                : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/ac/No_image_available.svg/600px-No_image_available.svg.png",
          }}
        />
        <View>
          <Text>{room.name}</Text>
          <Button
            title="Go to room"
            onPress={() => {
              navigation.navigate("Room", { roomID: room.id });
              console.log("clicked room id: " + room.id);
            }}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  ));
}
```

```
function RoomScreen(route, navigation) {
  const { roomID } = route.params; // Cannot read property 'roomID' of undefined
  //const roomID = "33290044-5232-46be-9302-210f5291905b"; //hardcoded value
  const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(GET_MESSAGES, {
    variables: { roomID: roomID },
  });
//fragment
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution here:

```
function RoomScreen(props) {
  const roomID = props.route.params.roomID;
```

Comment: or `function RoomScreen( {route, navigation} ) {` ?

Answer (score 0):

The function RoomScreen return props(object) which has params, navigation and other props, so you can use it like this

```
function RoomScreen(props) {
  const {roomID} = props.route.params;
  ...
}
```

or you can destructure that returning object like this

```
function RoomScreen({route, navigation}) {
  const {roomID} = route.params;
  ...
}
```

As you did it in HomeScreen.